# Which time value gets assigned to kafka record message.timestamp (kafka-python library)?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

In the official documentation of kafka-python library there is literally nothing about what value is assigned to a consumed record `.timestamp` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The value of this Kafka timestamp depends on the `log.message.timestamp.type` broker configuration (see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#log.message.timestamp.type), which can be set to `CreateTime` (i.e client producer timestamp) or `LogAppendTime` (i.e broker timestamp).

Here's an extract of the [producer client documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback-) that clarifies it:

> If CreateTime is used by the topic, the timestamp will be the user provided timestamp or the record send time if the user did not specify a timestamp for the record. If LogAppendTime is used for the topic, the timestamp will be the Kafka broker local time when the message is appended.

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarification. Do you know by chance where/how i could change this parameter? Do i simply add it in the server.properties file?

Comment: Yes, to configure it globally for all topics of the Kafka cluster, you simply add it to the `server.properties` file. You can also set it for each specific topic by adding `--config "message.timestamp.type=..."` when you create it (or update it with `kafka-topics.sh`)

Comment: happy to help :) (please upvote and accept the answer if you find it useful)